# When I upload nextjs on vercel I get such error - __dirname is not defined

Tags: github, next.js, vercel

I have nextjs project on vercel, but after deployment, I get a such error "ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined", what do you think is the problem? and how I can fix it.
As long as I merged the "client" and "server" files on Github, it worked fine. That is, I had "client" and "server" files separately on GitHub and I want to make this file into one repository and I did, but as I said, after merging this file, I get a __dirname error on vercel, only the client side